# Dailymotion embed video ui-theme and highlight color

Tags: user-interface, html5-video, dailymotion-api

Hi i need an example of how to change the theme and highlight color of the new Dailymotion player i use ui-theme and ui-hightlight as the Dailymotion guide indicates ([link](https://developer.dailymotion.com/player#player-parameters)) or I just use highlight like some examples said but nothing happens.

```
<iframe id="iframe-video" width="16" height="9" src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x3mfcoi?highlight=FF0000" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not using the right parameter in the example you gave, this is why it's not working. As defined in [the documentation](https://developer.dailymotion.com/player#player-parameters), the relevant params are:
- ui-highlight
- ui-theme

For example, the following embed has the highlight color set to #FF0000:
`http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x2m8jpp_dailymotion-spirit-movie_creation?ui-highlight=FF0000`

Note that you can't set a light highlight and light theme (and similarly, a dark highlight and dark theme), otherwise the control buttons are not visible. You can read more about it in our [section related to player customisation](https://developer.dailymotion.com/player#player-customisation).